# SQL Azure - The type of column "" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list

Tags: azure-sql-database, unpivot

we are migrating our Sql Server Stored Procedures to Sql Azure. We are getting below error when trying to create a Stored Procedure on Sql Azure

> Error Message: Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
> SP_Get_EmployeeGeneralDetails, Line 64 [Batch Start Line 6] The type
> of column "EmployeeName" conflicts with the type of other columns
> specified in the UNPIVOT list.

SP Script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Get_EmployeeGeneralDetails]
(
 @moduleID INT
,@templateID INT
,@employeeId INT
,@locationID INT
,@applicationID INT
,@culture NVARCHAR(20)
,@letterBody NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
)
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @typeId INT

    SELECT  @typeId = TypeId
    FROM    tCultureMaster
    WHERE   CultureCode = @culture
   
    DECLARE @symbolChangeTable TABLE
        (
         [Key] NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,[Value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
        )
   
    INSERT  INTO @symbolChangeTable
            SELECT  [Key]
                   ,[Value]
            FROM    ( SELECT    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), GETDATE(),107) AS [Date]
                               ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ve.FullName) AS EmployeeName
                                                   --,ve.FullName AS EmployeeName  ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ve.FullName) AS EmployeeName
                               ,CASE @typeId
                                  WHEN 1
                                  THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ve.Designation) /*English*/
                                  ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ve.DesignationArabic) /*Arabic*/
                                END AS Designation   --Column Name
                               ,CASE @typeId
                                  WHEN 1
                                  THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ve.Department) /*English*/
                                  ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ve.DepartmentArabic) /*Arabic*/
                                END AS Department   --Column Name
                               ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), l.CompanyName) AS CompanyName
                               ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), te.LastPromotionDate) AS LastPromotionDate
                               ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), veHr.FullName) AS HRAdmin
                      FROM      tEmployee te
                                INNER JOIN dbo.v_Employees ve ON ve.EmployeeID = te.EmployeeId
                                INNER JOIN dbo.tLocation l ON l.LocationCode = te.LocationId
                                INNER JOIN dbo.v_Employees veHR ON veHR.EmployeeID = l.HRManager
                      WHERE     te.EmployeeId = @employeeId
                                AND te.LocationId = @locationID
                    ) pvt UNPIVOT
            ( [Value] FOR [Key] IN ( [Date], EmployeeName, Designation,
                                     Department, CompanyName,
                                     LastPromotionDate, HRAdmin
                                      ) ) AS unpvt

    --Common Section for all Modules   

    DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT  @body = Body
    FROM    tLetterTemplates lt
    WHERE   TemplateID = @templateID
            AND ModuleID = @moduleID
           

    DECLARE @key NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@value NVARCHAR(MAX)

    DECLARE cur_SymbolList CURSOR FOR SELECT  [Key], [Value]
    FROM    @symbolChangeTable

    OPEN cur_SymbolList
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_SymbolList INTO @key, @value

    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @body = REPLACE(CAST(@body AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
                                '#' + @key + '#', @value) ;
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur_SymbolList INTO @key, @value
        END

    SET @letterBody = @body ;    

    --PRINT @body ;
    --SELECT  @body;
END
```

This stored Procedure gets created as correctly on Sql Server but gives error on SQL Azure.

All the columns in UnPivot have same type, NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: A little strange that I tried your script and there is no error in my Azure SQL database.

Comment: Hi Leon, thanks for your efforts. We are new to SQL Azure. Could you kindly let us know whether there is any version / edition / configuration we need to look for in SQL Azure. May be there are environment differences in yours and our, due to which the issue occurs in our SQL Azure and not in yours.

Comment: My Azure SQL database is version V12.0.2000.8. I didn't set anything just with the default settings.

Comment: I run it in SSMS.

Comment: please share your sample script which you executed and there were no errors. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @shoab, I put this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can run this script in Azure SQL database and without any error. Please see the screenshot:
[image]

My Azure SQL database is version V12.0.2000.8. I didn't set anything just with the default settings.

The script is copy from you question:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Get_EmployeeGeneralDetails]
(
 @moduleID INT
,@templateID INT
,@employeeId INT
,@locationID INT
,@applicationID INT
,@culture NVARCHAR(20)
,@letterBody NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
)
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @typeId INT

    SELECT  @typeId = TypeId
    FROM    tCultureMaster
    WHERE   CultureCode = @culture
   
    DECLARE @symbolChangeTable TABLE
        (
         [Key] NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,[Value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
        )
   
    INSERT  INTO @symbolChangeTable
            SELECT  [Key]
                   ,[Value]
            FROM    ( SELECT    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), GETDATE(),107) AS [Date]
                               ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ve.FullName) AS EmployeeName
                                                   --,ve.FullName AS EmployeeName  ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ve.FullName) AS EmployeeName
                               ,CASE @typeId
                                  WHEN 1
                                  THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ve.Designation) /*English*/
                                  ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ve.DesignationArabic) /*Arabic*/
                                END AS Designation   --Column Name
                               ,CASE @typeId
                                  WHEN 1
                                  THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ve.Department) /*English*/
                                  ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ve.DepartmentArabic) /*Arabic*/
                                END AS Department   --Column Name
                               ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), l.CompanyName) AS CompanyName
                               ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), te.LastPromotionDate) AS LastPromotionDate
                               ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), veHr.FullName) AS HRAdmin
                      FROM      tEmployee te
                                INNER JOIN dbo.v_Employees ve ON ve.EmployeeID = te.EmployeeId
                                INNER JOIN dbo.tLocation l ON l.LocationCode = te.LocationId
                                INNER JOIN dbo.v_Employees veHR ON veHR.EmployeeID = l.HRManager
                      WHERE     te.EmployeeId = @employeeId
                                AND te.LocationId = @locationID
                    ) pvt UNPIVOT
            ( [Value] FOR [Key] IN ( [Date], EmployeeName, Designation,
                                     Department, CompanyName,
                                     LastPromotionDate, HRAdmin
                                      ) ) AS unpvt

    --Common Section for all Modules   

    DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT  @body = Body
    FROM    tLetterTemplates lt
    WHERE   TemplateID = @templateID
            AND ModuleID = @moduleID
           

    DECLARE @key NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@value NVARCHAR(MAX)

    DECLARE cur_SymbolList CURSOR FOR SELECT  [Key], [Value]
    FROM    @symbolChangeTable

    OPEN cur_SymbolList
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_SymbolList INTO @key, @value

    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @body = REPLACE(CAST(@body AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
                                '#' + @key + '#', @value) ;
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur_SymbolList INTO @key, @value
        END

    SET @letterBody = @body ;    

    --PRINT @body ;
    --SELECT  @body;
END
```

Comment: excuse me Leon, looking at the screen shot you shared, seems liked you had parsed the script and it didn't gave error. For us too parse doesn't gives error. Error occurs when executing the script (F5).

Comment: @shoab I click the `Execute` to run the script. Did you use SSMS? Please try it.

Comment: @shoab did you get any progresses?